# Looping generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I need to make the graph and I want to the edges and the vertices to be generic type

```
public interface IVertex<TVertex, TEdge>
        where TVertex : IVertex<?>
        where TEdge : IEdge<?>
{
    bool AddEdge(TEdge e);
    TEdge FindEdge(TVertex v);
}

public interface IEdge<TVertex> where TVertex : IVertex<?>
{
    TVertex From { get; }
}
```

But, the edge required the vertex type and the vertex required the edge type
What should I do?

Comment: `TEdge FindEdge(TVertex v);` what does this method do?

Comment: I really wish someone gave a workaround to this one as making a non-generic `IVertex` over generic `IVertex<T>` or adding `TItem` to the `IVertex<TVertex, TEdge>` generic parameters are the only solutions I have ever met so far.

Comment: I think this question needs an explanation of why you want the generic type parameters. Give an example where removing all the `TVertex`s and `TEdge`s and replacing them with `IVertex` and `IEdge` (on method/property signatures) wouldn't be sufficient, so we understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're making it more complicated then it needs to be.
Would something like this work?

```
public interface IVertex<T>
{
    bool AddEdge(IEdge<T> e);
    IEdge<T> FindEdge(IVertex<T> v);
}

public interface IEdge<T>
{
    IVertex<T> From { get; }
}
```

Comment: What do the Ts represent?

Comment: @BenAaronson [Generic Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx)

Comment: @stuartd Er, right, but what specifically do those type parameters represent in this case? In the question, there's two types, `TVertex` and `TEdge`, which are respectively constrained to implement `IVertex` and `IEdge`. In this case `T` seems to be a totally unconstrained type

Comment: @BenAaronson I guess it's the data type of whatever the vertices can hold. But I see this solution may not be what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @BenAaronson `T`s are for `?` generic types in the question

Comment: @Dennis_E Yeah, without knowing what the OP is trying to achieve, it's hard to know whether this solves the problem or not

Answer (score 3):

While it's arguable whether or not it's actually a good idea, there's nothing the compiler minds about such "looping" definitions:

```
interface IVertex<TVertex, TEdge> where TVertex : IVertex<TVertex,TEdge>
                                  where TEdge : IEdge<TVertex,TEdge>
{

}

interface IEdge<TVertex, TEdge> where TVertex : IVertex<TVertex, TEdge>
                                where TEdge : IEdge<TVertex, TEdge>
{

}
```

Then you can write, for example:

```
class FooVertex : IVertex<FooVertex,BarEdge>
{

}

class BarEdge : IEdge<FooVertex,BarEdge>
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want edge and vertex stores some value. If you want vertexes have `TV` values and edges have `TE` values you can do something like this:

```
public interface IVertex<TV, TE>
{
    TV Value { get; }
    bool AddEdge(IEdge<TV, TE> e);
    IEdge<TV, TE> FindEdge(IVertex<TV, TE> v);
}

public interface IEdge<TV, TE> 
{
    TE Value { get; }
    IVertex<TV, TE> From { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have created a recursive definition with your type constraints. You are saying that `IVertex<A>` where `A` must be `IVertex<B>`, where `B` must be `IVertex<C>`, etc... At some point you must specify actually specify a type or interface as your generic parameter. A couple good solutions have already been suggested. Here is another in case you need more options...

You could introduce another type or interface(non-generic) to break the recursive definition.

```
public interface IVertex<TVertex, TEdge>
        where TVertex : IVertex
        where TEdge : IEdge
{
    bool AddEdge(TEdge e);
    TEdge FindEdge(TVertex v);
}

public interface IEdge<TVertex> where TVertex : IVertex
{
    TVertex From { get; }
}
```